# boost property tree add_child specifying the path

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm using boost::property_tree to manipulate some XML.  I have to add a subnode to an xml document

The xml document looks like so:

```
<MPD>
    <Period>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:9a04f079-9840-4286-ab92-e65be0885f95">
                <!-- value already exists here //-->
                <!-- need to insert new entry here //-->
            </ContentProtection>
        </AdaptationSet>

        <AdaptationSet>
            <ContentProtection ... />
            <ContentProtection ... />
            <ContentProtection ... />
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

So I have the following code to insert new entry in the place marked in the XML above:

```
typedef boost::property_tree::iptree        property_tree_t;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<property_tree_t>  shared_ptree_t;
typedef boost::optional<property_tree_t &>  optional_ptree_t;

string sSearchSchemeIdUri = "urn:uuid:9a04f079-9840-4286-ab92-e65be0885f95";
string sChildName;

optional_ptree_t spPeriod = spPTree->get_child_optional("MPD.Period");
if (spPeriod)
{
    for (auto & adaptSetNextChild : spPeriod->get_child("AdaptationSet"))
    {
        sChildName = adaptSetNextChild.first;

        if (sChildName.compare("ContentProtection") == 0)
        {
            property_tree_t &   ptContentProtection = adaptSetNextChild.second;
            string              sSchemeIdUri        = ptContentProtection.get<string>("<xmlattr>.schemeIdUri", "");

            if (sSchemeIdUri.compare(sSearchSchemeIdUri) == 0)
            {
                property_tree_t ptPssh;
                ptPssh.clear();
                ptPssh.add("cenc:PSSH", sPssh);
                ptContentProtection.add_child("./", ptPssh);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code wraps the added data in the following:

```
<></>
<//></>
```

Which I'd like to avoid.

This erroneous markup is coming i presume from my add_child call, that specifies the insert path as "./"

Specifying nothing causes an exception, and this is the only thing I found that works.

Having read [the header file for ptree.hp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp)p, which states that the argument is

```
/** Add the node at the given path. Create any missing parents. If there
* already is a node at the path, add another one with the same key.
* @param path Path to the child. The last fragment must not have an
*             index.
* @return A reference to the inserted subtree.
* @note Because of the way paths work, it is not generally guaranteed
*       that a node newly created can be accessed using the same path.
*/
self_type &add_child(const path_type &path, const self_type &value);
```

Is there any way to specify the current path, eg. the path for ptContentProtection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have the `put` members instead of the `add` members.

Here's a sample that replaces `OLD VALUE` with `NEW VALUE`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ae75504e5eb658e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

static std::string const sample = R"(<MPD>
    <Period>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
            <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:9a04f079-9840-4286-ab92-e65be0885f95">OLD VALUE</ContentProtection>
        </AdaptationSet>

        <AdaptationSet>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>)";

static std::string sSearchSchemeIdUri = "urn:uuid:9a04f079-9840-4286-ab92-e65be0885f95";

int main() {
    using boost::property_tree::iptree;
    iptree pt;
    {
        std::istringstream iss(sample);
        read_xml(iss, pt);
    }

    for (auto& as : pt.get_child("MPD.Period")) {
        if (as.first == "AdaptationSet") {
            for (auto& cp : as.second) {
                if (cp.first == "ContentProtection" && cp.second.get("<xmlattr>.schemeIdUri", "") == sSearchSchemeIdUri)
                {
                    cp.second.put_value("NEW VALUE");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    auto xws = boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4);
    write_xml(std::cout, pt, xws);
}
```

Comment: Added a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ae75504e5eb658e)